# Combining Modules Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-activity

I'm doing an Android project on Eclipse and I have 2 independent apps sources(Modules). How do I combine these two modules, such that when a button (present on first app) is clicked, the second app is launched?
As far I've just created the button and that's it.Any Help would be appreciated.
As I'm a beginner, please be specific :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest of the second app :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivitySecondApp"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.external.intentReceiver" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And then place the following code inside the onClickListener of the Button in the first App :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.external.intentReceiver");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

So, when the button is clicked, an intent of the type `com.external.intentReceiver` will be fired. The `MainActivitySecondApp` will then open since it is meant to handle such intents as defined in the Manifest.

Comment: Hello Shivam, I tried doing your suggestion but it turns out i didn't understand quite well. Here is the mainfest of second app: <activity
    android:name=".MainActivitySecondApp"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.external.intentReceiver" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>      This app is named image-chooser-app, and here's from OnClickListener button of first app named: Loginexample:

Comment: What didnt you understand ?

Comment: Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction("com.external.intentReceiver");
       context.startActivity(intent);"
            android:text="Import!" />

Comment: Heres a cleaner version: http://pastebin.com/RWqSVaMF    &   http://pastebin.com/wZtyFgtH

Comment: So any idea how i can do it? :( Its my College project and im just a beginner :(

Comment: add the intent part of code inside button click listener inside onCreate

Comment: Im getting "attribute is missing the android namespace prefix" error

Comment: Sorry man, you need to learn the basics of android first. Maybe check out beginner tutorials on android dev website.